# class made with toggleClass() doesn't alert on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Another `toggleClass()` problem. There are dozens question about this jQuery function but I could not find this specific one.

I have 2 buttons. One toggles the class of the other on click. This works fine since the colour changes, however when I use a `click()` event on the 'new' class nothing happens.

**html**

```
<button type='button' id='button1'>button 1</button>
<button type='button' id='button2'>button 2</button>
```

**css**

```
.pushed {
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

**js**

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
  $('#button2').toggleClass('pushed');
});

$('.pushed').click(function () {
  alert('pushed!')
});
```

you can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/tk9pt3o2/

Comment: @Rob the edit is not correct... the color changes, the problem is that it does not alert 'pushed'

Comment: Then edit your title to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you select the element with `.pushed` before even exists. Try to use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pushed',function () {
  alert('pushed!')
});
```

`on` will bind the click event to the current matched elements and future matched elements.

Comment: yes, makes sense... exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you can just register event for an existing Dom elements.
the key point is $('.pushed') return jquery object with no element to register the event on it.